# Start ubiquity through ssh

Tags: 20.04, ssh, ubiquity

I'm trying to start ubiquity through ssh. X11Forwarding is enabled.

I type this :

```bash
$ ssh kubuntu@192.168.1.77
kubuntu@192.168.1.77's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-27-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
Last login: Fri Nov  5 17:39:41 2021 from 192.168.1.4
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ ubiquity kde_ui 
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$
```

But via `sudo`, it works and opens the Ubiquity GUI :

```bash
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ xhost 
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:root
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ test -z "$XAUTHORITY" && export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo ubiquity kde_ui
```

Is this fine to run the installer as `sudo` ?

Comment: Try it :-) If it works, fine, otherwise nothing dangerous will happen, it will 'only' fail.

Comment: @sudodus The installation is stalled at 0%. So I will try the normal installation now.

Comment: @sudodus My `/` partition was 5G instead of at least 5.8G as the Ubiquity Installer says and I didn't format the filesystems in Ubiquity because I created them manually and formated them BEFORE running Ubiquity. So I won't know why it stalled today.